# Explode a string based on Last closing bracket

Tags: php

I want to explode a string based on  certain condition .

I tried a number of ways , but cannot get it work properly .

**String**

Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : rlm_perl: PPPoE.Auth.INFO: educationhome, NAS_IP 133.1.92.86, PAY_PLAN 0, CLIENT_MAC 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14) Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [educationhome] (from client mikrotik port 15833926 cli 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14) Thu Jul 13 10:45:44 2017 : Auth: Invalid user (Account has expired [Expiration 09 Jul 2017]): [chudamanimrg] (from client mikrotik port 16076961 cli 80:2A:A8:0E:37:FE)

**Expected Output**

```
array(
'Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : rlm_perl: PPPoE.Auth.INFO: educationhome, NAS_IP 113.1.92.86, PAY_PLAN 0, CLIENT_MAC 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14',
'Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [educationhome] (from client mikrotik port 15833926 cli 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14)',
'Thu Jul 13 10:45:44 2017 : Auth: Invalid user (Account has expired [Expiration 09 Jul 2017]): [chudamanimrg] (from client mikrotik port 16076961 cli 80:2A:A8:0E:37:FE)'
);
```

I tried exploding it with current day `Thr` but then it wouldnt work for the old logs `('Wed' Tue' ....)`

```
$day = date("D");
$lines = explode($day,$lines);
```

I want to explode the string `$lines` based on the name of the day

```
$arr = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thr','Fri','Sat'];
```

I am not being able to do it correctly.

Comment: Show the exact desired output

Comment: @peterm I did update the question.

Comment: Use a regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `preg_split` and `array_chunk` functions:

```
$lines = 'Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : rlm_perl: PPPoE.Auth.INFO: educationhome, NAS_IP 103.1.92.86, PAY_PLAN 0, CLIENT_MAC 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14 Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [educationhome] (from client mikrotik port 15833926 cli 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14) Thu Jul 13 10:45:44 2017 : Auth: Invalid user (Account has expired [Expiration 09 Jul 2017]): [chudamanimrg] (from client mikrotik port 16076961 cli 80:2A:A8:0E:37:FE) ';
$days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

$result = preg_split('/\b(' . implode('|', $days). ')\b/', $lines, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$result = array_map(function($v){
    return $v[0] . $v[1];
}, array_chunk($result, 2));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : rlm_perl: PPPoE.Auth.INFO: educationhome, NAS_IP 103.1.92.86, PAY_PLAN 0, CLIENT_MAC 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14 
    [1] => Thu Jul 13 10:45:37 2017 : Auth: Login OK: [educationhome] (from client mikrotik port 15833926 cli 80:2A:A8:6C:F6:14) 
    [2] => Thu Jul 13 10:45:44 2017 : Auth: Invalid user (Account has expired [Expiration 09 Jul 2017]): [chudamanimrg] (from client mikrotik port 16076961 cli 80:2A:A8:0E:37:FE) 
)
```

---

[Demo link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3846d620367a49aab84296ec28ee91db571f1bb9)